# I have two arrays, i need to print first element from first array and first element from second array and so on

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my XML data

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Library>
<Books>
   <Book>
       <Name>Me Before You</Name>
       <Author>Jojo Moyes</Author>
   </Book>
<Book>
       <Name>Chitra</Name>
       <Author>Rabhindranath Tagore</Author>
   </Book>
<Book>
       <Name>Wings of Fire</Name>
       <Author>A P J Abdul Kalam</Author>
   </Book>
</Books>

</Library>
```

This is the code I have return to parse the data:

```
//Some variables are declared globally.

//XML file getting from the upload
var request = new Request(`https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/${this.state.ipfsHash}`);
  fetch(request).then((results) => {
    // results returns XML. lets cast this to a string, then create
    // a new DOM object out of it!
    var values=[];
    var value=[];
    var i='';
    var j='';
    results
      .text()
      .then(( str ) => {
        this.state.responseDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'application/xml');
        console.log(this.state.responseDoc);

//storing in array            
        this.state.listItem  = this.state.responseDoc.getElementsByTagName('Name');
        this.state.listItems  = this.state.responseDoc.getElementsByTagName('Author');

//Using for loop
        for (i=0; i<this.state.listItem.length; i++){
          values.push(this.state.responseDoc.getElementsByTagName('Name')[i].textContent);
        }   
        for (j=0; j<this.state.listItems.length; j++){
       value.push(this.state.responseDoc.getElementsByTagName('Author')[j].textContent);
        }

          this.setState({liItem: values});
         this.setState({liItems: value});
      })
    });
```

In render i'm using this code to display output:

```html
<table border="2">
        <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Author</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
            <td>{this.state.liItem.map(x => {return x + '\n';})}</td>
            <td>{this.state.liItems.map(y => {return y + '\n';})}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Expected Output:

```
Me Before You
JoJo Moyes and so on...
```

Output I'm getting:

```
Me Before You    Jojo Moyes
Chitra    Rabhindranath Tagore
Wings of Fire    A P J Abdul Kalam
```

Tried assigning the j < i in j for loop, but it's coming differently like book names and author name for one iteration, then 2 author name for 2nd iteration.
Tried changing so many things but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

To display on a new line:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{this.state.liItem.map(x => {return x + '\n';})}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{this.state.liItems.map(y => {return y + '\n';})}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

However, it does not seem like a table is a good structure to display this data from the code you have provided. Maybe you should look into a list?

```
<ul>
        <li>{this.state.liItem.map(x => {return x + '\n';})}</li>
        <li>{this.state.liItems.map(y => {return y + '\n';})}</li>
</ul>
```

Okay, you need to store the values together, javascript objects will do the trick, this is assuming you don't have multiple authors with the same name:

```
//loading and storing the variables
var responseDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'application/xml');
console.log(responseDoc);

//store in a map           
var names  = this.state.responseDoc.getElementsByTagName('Name');
var authors  = this.state.responseDoc.getElementsByTagName('Author');

//Using for loop
for (i=0; i<names.length; i++){
  //create an object
  let name = names[i].textContext
  let author = author[i].textContext 
  let object = {}
  object[name] = author
  values.push(object);
}   
this.setState({
  objectArray: values,
  objectArraySet: true
}) 


//in the render method

<table border="2">
  <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Author</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  {this.displayObjects()}

  </tbody>
</table>


//a method to display the values into the dom
    displayObjects(){
      var dom_array = []
      if(this.state.objectArraySet){
        Object.keys(this.state.objectArray).map(function(key, index){
          dom_array.push(
            <tr>
              <td>
                {key} : {this.state.ObjectArray[key]}
              </td>
            </tr>
          )    
        }, this)
        return dom_array
      } return null
    }
```

Comment: output is same. But the output i need is 

Book Name & Author Name.

But I'm getting all books names first later all author names

Comment: @KalyanA i've updated my answer, let me know if this explains it better

Comment: Your help is appreciated @J Dorrian. But the solution is throwing error at tr in displayObjects(). It is throwing error 0 undefinded.

Comment: @KalyanA Put console.log('Item ', index , 'with: ' , key) inside the .map function before the push